# How do I convert a Morningstar report format to timeseries?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I extracted a Morningstar report for 4 funds in the below format. Columns A, B, C, D are rolling data points (eg: 1/1/2013 - 12/31/2013 A is data point A rolled over 12 months). I want to convert the dataset into a timeseries, with these rolled data points to be tagged with date end of rolling period, so 12/31/2012 in this case.

```
d = [{'fund': 'Fund ABC',
  'val1': 1,
  'val2': 2,
  'val3': 'high',
  '1/1/2013 - 12/31/2013 A': 94.529477,
  '1/1/2013 - 12/31/2013 B': 19.425042,
  '1/1/2013 - 12/31/2013 C': 103.6619,
  '1/1/2013 - 12/31/2013 D': 0.966762,
  '2/1/2013 - 1/31/2014 A': 91.275272,
  '2/1/2013 - 1/31/2014 B': 23.741808,
  '2/1/2013 - 1/31/2014 C': 100.659278,
  '2/1/2013 - 1/31/2014 D': 0.945206,
  '3/1/2013 - 2/28/2014 A': 94.529477,
  '3/1/2013 - 2/28/2014 B': 19.425042,
  '3/1/2013 - 2/28/2014 C': 103.6619,
  '3/1/2013 - 2/28/2014 D': 0.966762},
 {'fund': 'Fund DEF',
  'val1': 2,
  'val2': 4,
  'val3': 'high',
  '1/1/2013 - 12/31/2013 A': 94.585111,
  '1/1/2013 - 12/31/2013 B': 19.452069,
  '1/1/2013 - 12/31/2013 C': 103.025084,
  '1/1/2013 - 12/31/2013 D': 0.961847,
  '2/1/2013 - 1/31/2014 A': 91.341703,
  '2/1/2013 - 1/31/2014 B': 23.611624,
  '2/1/2013 - 1/31/2014 C': 99.635705,
  '2/1/2013 - 1/31/2014 D': 0.936586,
  '3/1/2013 - 2/28/2014 A': 94.585111,
  '3/1/2013 - 2/28/2014 B': 19.452069,
  '3/1/2013 - 2/28/2014 C': 103.025084,
  '3/1/2013 - 2/28/2014 D': 0.961847},
 {'fund': 'Fund GHI',
  'val1': 25,
  'val2': 6,
  'val3': 'low',
  '1/1/2013 - 12/31/2013 A': 96.16331,
  '1/1/2013 - 12/31/2013 B': 17.508856,
  '1/1/2013 - 12/31/2013 C': 99.658363,
  '1/1/2013 - 12/31/2013 D': 1.047576,
  '2/1/2013 - 1/31/2014 A': 94.273842,
  '2/1/2013 - 1/31/2014 B': 21.576599,
  '2/1/2013 - 1/31/2014 C': 99.180184,
  '2/1/2013 - 1/31/2014 D': 0.968538,
  '3/1/2013 - 2/28/2014 A': 96.16331,
  '3/1/2013 - 2/28/2014 B': 17.508856,
  '3/1/2013 - 2/28/2014 C': 99.658363,
  '3/1/2013 - 2/28/2014 D': 1.047576},
 {'fund': 'Fund JKL',
  'val1': 3,
  'val2': 5,
  'val3': 'low',
  '1/1/2013 - 12/31/2013 A': 96.031607,
  '1/1/2013 - 12/31/2013 B': 17.477078,
  '1/1/2013 - 12/31/2013 C': 100.181228,
  '1/1/2013 - 12/31/2013 D': 1.052654,
  '2/1/2013 - 1/31/2014 A': 94.017587,
  '2/1/2013 - 1/31/2014 B': 21.599133,
  '2/1/2013 - 1/31/2014 C': 99.744179,
  '2/1/2013 - 1/31/2014 D': 0.973494,
  '3/1/2013 - 2/28/2014 A': 96.031607,
  '3/1/2013 - 2/28/2014 B': 17.477078,
  '3/1/2013 - 2/28/2014 C': 100.181228,
  '3/1/2013 - 2/28/2014 D': 1.052654}]
df =pd.DataFrame(d)
df
```

Input:
[image]

Expected Output:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
df1 = df.set_axis(df.columns.str.replace(r'(.*) - (.*) ([ABCD])', r'\3-\2', regex=True), axis=1)

out = pd.wide_to_long(df1, stubnames=list('ABCD'),
                      i=['fund', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3'], j='date',
                      sep='-', suffix='.*').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
        fund  val1  val2  val3        date          A          B           C         D
0   Fund ABC     1     2  high  12/31/2013  94.529477  19.425042  103.661900  0.966762
1   Fund ABC     1     2  high   1/31/2014  91.275272  23.741808  100.659278  0.945206
2   Fund ABC     1     2  high   2/28/2014  94.529477  19.425042  103.661900  0.966762
3   Fund DEF     2     4  high  12/31/2013  94.585111  19.452069  103.025084  0.961847
4   Fund DEF     2     4  high   1/31/2014  91.341703  23.611624   99.635705  0.936586
5   Fund DEF     2     4  high   2/28/2014  94.585111  19.452069  103.025084  0.961847
6   Fund GHI    25     6   low  12/31/2013  96.163310  17.508856   99.658363  1.047576
7   Fund GHI    25     6   low   1/31/2014  94.273842  21.576599   99.180184  0.968538
8   Fund GHI    25     6   low   2/28/2014  96.163310  17.508856   99.658363  1.047576
9   Fund JKL     3     5   low  12/31/2013  96.031607  17.477078  100.181228  1.052654
10  Fund JKL     3     5   low   1/31/2014  94.017587  21.599133   99.744179  0.973494
11  Fund JKL     3     5   low   2/28/2014  96.031607  17.477078  100.181228  1.052654
```